# Can i load an in memory XML, returned by a linq to SQL query, to an SWF object?

Tags: asp.net, xml, flash, actionscript-3, swfobject

Can i load an in memory XML, returned by a linq to SQL query, to an SWF object?

And here comes the long version.

The purpose is loading an in-memory XML file, to an SWFobject via a querystring.

Currently i read and load the XML file from an absolute path.

```
var flashvars = {xmlPath: "xml/" + GetQueryString("x") + ".xml" };
  var params = { allowFullScreen: "true", wmode: "transparent" };
  var attributes = {};
  swfobject.embedSWF("main.swf", "gallery", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Unfortunately or fortunately the solution above is not elegant since i have to create and save the XML file to my webserver and then load it to the SWFobject from an absolute path...

Which gives me errors like the following, when i try to save the file...

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\images\76df249e-83c3-413d-8664-c6f7b289c32c\data.xml' is denied.
```

So what can i do to make it work?
Can i load an in-memory XML file to an SWFobect bypassing the absolute-relative paths?

If so how can i do it?

I am sure you do not create files in every query and save them in web-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed whole xml in flashvars.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. You mean something like... var flashvars = {xmlPath: XmlFromMemory }; ?? Sorry but i am a newbie

Comment: You can get xml contents to string, right? Put into into flashvars object: var flashvars = {xml: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding=..." };
SWF needs to be updated too, it should not load file from xmlPath, just use what's in xml parameter.

Comment: I think i found a more elegant solution. I create the Xml on the fly with an .aspx page that returns an xml. But the most importand is that i learned my lesson. Thank you.